# How to rotate marker image for MapKit

Tags: mapkit

I have a custom image for a marker and based upon some data the rotation of the image needs to be changed. The image in question is a boat and based upon the boat's heading at a given moment I want to rotate the image to reflect and match this. How can I do this in MapKit?